# How to make cljs files works with figwheel repl via fireplace.vim?

Tags: vim, clojurescript, read-eval-print-loop

I have a project on ClojureScript and I'm using vim for code editing, so I want to access repl inside editor, what is accessible using fireplace.vim.

It works well if you have a brand new flat project - you just open the directory, start clojure repl, open vim in the same directory, create an expression and evaluate it using cpp.

https://youtu.be/vHDLDNoAdLE

But when I working with figwheel project I want to connect to figwheel repl in order to calculate something from cljs file, so I start a figwheel which starts the repl on port 7888 eventually and connect to that repl with fireplace using :Connect command and it works for only clj files, not for cljs.

https://youtu.be/ue42Yh0v6UQ

When I'm trying to evaluate an expression in .cljs file fireplace throwing this error:

> Error detected while processing function
> 37_printop[1](https://youtu.be/vHDLDNoAdLE)..37_opfunc[35]..fireplace#client: line   10:
> E605: Exception not caught: Fireplace: class
> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

Does anyone have any idea how to make it work (fireplace + .cjls files)?

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but I can recommend checking out [Spacemacs](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs) with the [Clojure layer](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/tree/master/layers/%2Blang/clojure). You have great Vim bindings and the Clojure integration works out of the box.

Comment: Thank you for recomendation. I've tried to use Spacemacs, but I really stick to vim. Maybe it will be last resort if I won't manage the issue with cljs files.

Answer (score 1):

Have you "Piggiebacked" ("enable the use of a ClojureScript REPL on top of an nREPL session") to connect Fireplace to the Figwheel REPL?

```
:Piggieback (figwheel-sidecar.repl-api/repl-env)
```

See https://github.com/bhauman/lein-figwheel/wiki/Using-the-Figwheel-REPL-with-Vim#still-in-vim-piggieback-on-clojurescript

Related to `ClassNotFound Exception cemmerick.piggieback`:

You have to include `cemerick.piggieback` in your `project.clj` or `profiles.clj`. See https://github.com/nrepl/piggieback:

```
:profiles {:dev {:dependencies [[com.cemerick/piggieback "0.2.1"]
                                [figwheel-sidecar "0.5.18"]]
                 :repl-options {:nrepl-middleware [cemerick.piggieback/wrap-cljs-repl]}}}
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer! I'll go deeply in that later and hope to make a success report.

Comment: After command : Piggieback (figwheel-sidecar.repl-api/repl-env) I receive next error - ClassNotFound Exception cemmerick.piggieback. What could be the reason?

Comment: Thank you, but it doesn't work for me. I'm still getting that error with cemmerick.piggieback and don't know where to move further...

Comment: I wonder why it compains about cemerick.piggieback while I have cider.piggieback?

Comment: Maybe use cemerick.piggieback. See https://github.com/bhauman/lein-figwheel/wiki/Using-the-Figwheel-REPL-with-Vim#setup: `[com.cemerick/piggieback "0.2.1"]` and `[cemerick.piggieback/wrap-cljs-repl]`. I updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was in fireplace.vim plugin

at line 323 in fireplace.vim

```
let response = connection.eval("((or (resolve 'cider.piggieback/cljs-repl)"
```

must be line:

```
let response = connection.eval("((or (resolve 'cider.piggieback/wrap-cljs-repl)"
```

because cider.piggieback defines wrap-cljs-repl function in line 299:

```
(defn wrap-cljs-repl [handler]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sequence of steps I took to make work figwheel REPL with vim fireplace:

1. Add these dependencies to `/home/{username}/.clojure/deps.edn`:

```clj
...
  :aliases {:nrepl
            {:extra-deps
             {nrepl/nrepl {:mvn/version "0.6.0"}
              cider/cider-nrepl {:mvn/version "0.23.0"}
              cider/piggieback {:mvn/version "0.4.2"}}}}
...
```

2. Add these ones to the project:

```clj
...
 :deps  {com.bhauman/figwheel-main {:mvn/version "0.2.3"}
         figwheel-sidecar          {:mvn/version "0.5.19"}}
...
```

3. Run a project from a terminal with the next command:

```sh
clj -R:nrepl -m nrepl.cmdline --middleware "[cider.nrepl/cider-middleware cider.piggieback/wrap-cljs-repl]"
```

4. Connect to an nREPL from vim using:

```
:Connect nrepl://localhost:{port}
```

5. Start a figwheel REPL and connect to it:

```
:CljEval (do (require 'figwheel.main.api) (figwheel.main.api/start "dev"))
:CljEval (do (use 'figwheel.main.api) (figwheel.main.api/cljs-repl "dev"))
```